I want to the group-hover only when the specified div is hoverd not when the whole container hoverd
In this code it supposed when the button Filter is hovered it will show a dropdown-menu with 2 buttons generation and type and when the generation is hovered it will show an other dropdown-menu
so to acheive that i used group it worked when i hover the button filter but it also shows directly the genartion dropdown eventough me i want to show the generation buttons only when the button generation is hovered
<div className='group relative'>
            <div className='flex flex-row px-2 py-1 rounded gap-2 items-center hover:bg-black hover:opacity-20 hover:text-white cursor-pointer'>
              <img src={images.filter_icon} className='w-6 h-6 object-cover group-hover:hidden' alt="" />
              <img src={images.filter_hover_icon} className='w-6 h-6 object-cover group-hover:block hidden' />
              <p>Filter</p>
            </div>
            {/* Filter dropdown */}
            <div className='absolute -right-10 top-10 hidden dropdown-menu group-hover:block bg-gray-100 pl-6 pr-16 w-80 py-4 rounded'>
              <p className='mb-6 text-2xl'>Add Filter</p>
                   
                   {/* Generation */}
                  <div className='group- relative'>
                    <div className='bg-gray-200 w-full rounded hover:bg-slate-300 mb-4'>
                      <p className='p-3 cursor-pointer'>Generation</p>
                        {/* Generation dropdown*/}
                      <div className='absolute top-10 right-72 bg-gray-200 p-4 w-60 font-bold text-xl hidden group-hover:block'>
                        <p>Choose a generation</p>
                        <div className='flex flex-col gap-2 mt-6'>
                          <label className="flex flex-row gap-4 items-center">
                            <input type="checkbox" className="w-4 h-4 cursor-pointer" />
                            Generation 1
                          </label>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div className=' bg-gray-200 rounded hover:bg-slate-300'>
                    <p className='p-3 cursor-pointer'>Type</p>
                  </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className='group flex flex-row px-2 py-1 rounded gap-2 items-center hover:bg-black hover:opacity-20 hover:text-white cursor-pointer'>
            <img src={images.sort_icon} className='w-6 h-6 object-cover group-hover:hidden' alt="" />
            <img src={images.sort_hover_icon} className='w-5 h-5 object-cover group-hover:block hidden' />
            <p>Sort</p>
          </div>
      </div>

i tried using button click but i had problems like i want it to show just when its hovered

Parent div contain group when parent div is hover group-hover:
To use more group use group/name when it is hover group-hover/name:
see github discussion
example code
<div class="group/sidebar ...">
  <!-- ... -->
  <div class="group/navitem ...">
    <a
      href="#"
      class="opacity-50 group-hover/sidebar:opacity-75 group-hover/navitem:bg-black/75"
    >
      <!-- ... -->
    </a>
  </div>
  <!-- ... -->
</div>

Your updated code
<div className="group relative">
                <div className="flex flex-row px-2 py-1 rounded gap-2 items-center hover:bg-black hover:opacity-20 hover:text-white cursor-pointer">
                    <img
                        src="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/17782/17782068.png"
                        className="w-6 h-6 object-cover group-hover:hidden"
                        alt=""
                    />
                    <img
                        src="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/17782/17782068.png"
                        className="w-6 h-6 object-cover group-hover:block hidden"
                    />
                    <p>Filter</p>
                </div>
                {/* Filter dropdown */}
                <div className="absolute -right-10 top-10 hidden dropdown-menu group-hover:block bg-gray-100 pl-6 pr-16 w-80 py-4 rounded">
                    <p className="mb-6 text-2xl">Add Filter</p>
                    {/* Generation */}
                    <div className="group/generation relative">
                        <div className="bg-gray-200 w-full rounded hover:bg-slate-300 mb-4">
                            <p className="p-3 cursor-pointer">Generation</p>
                            {/* Generation dropdown*/}
                            <div className="absolute top-10 right-72 bg-gray-200 p-4 w-60 font-bold text-xl hidden group-hover/generation:block">
                                <p>Choose a generation</p>
                                <div className="flex flex-col gap-2 mt-6">
                                    <label className="flex flex-row gap-4 items-center">
                                        <input type="checkbox" className="w-4 h-4 cursor-pointer" />
                                        Generation 1
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className=" bg-gray-200 rounded hover:bg-slate-300">
                        <p className="p-3 cursor-pointer">Type</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="group flex flex-row px-2 py-1 rounded gap-2 items-center hover:bg-black hover:opacity-20 hover:text-white cursor-pointer">
                <img
                    src="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/17782/17782068.png"
                    className="w-6 h-6 object-cover group-hover:hidden"
                    alt=""
                />
                <img
                    src="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/17782/17782068.png"
                    className="w-5 h-5 object-cover group-hover:block hidden"
                />
                <p>Sort</p>
            </div>

